# Attractor $A$ with neighborhood $V$ such that $f^N(V)\subset V$ and $A=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}f^n(V)$, then $\omega(x)\subset A$ for all $x\in V$?

Tags: limits, dynamical-systems, invariance

Let $f\colon X\to X$ be a continuous map on a (compact) topological space $X$. Let $A$ be an attractor for $f$, i.e. there is a neighborhood $V$ of $A$ such that $f^N(V)\subset V$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $A=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}f^n(V)$. Now for $x\in V$, consider the set $\omega(x)$ of all $\omega$-limit points of $x$, i.e.
$$
\omega(x)=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\overline{\left\{f^k(x): k>n\right\}}.
$$
(You can see this definition of $\omega(x)$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_set) if you like.)

> > Now, I am interested to know whether
> >     $$
> > \omega(x)\subset A~\forall x\in V.
> > $$

Let $x\in V, y\in\omega(x)$. Then, by definition,
$$
y\in\overline{\left\{f^k(x): k>n\right\}}~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.~~~~~(*)
$$
In order to have $y\in A$, it would be necessary that 
$$
y\in f^n(V)~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.~~~~~~~(+)
$$

I do not see that in general $(*)$ does imply $(+)$.

**Edit**

If $V$ is closed (I guess this is the case since it is not said that $V$ is an open neighborhood of $A$) and $f(V)\subset V$, i.e. $N=1$, then $(*)$ should imply that $y\in f^n(\overline{V})=f^n(V)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e. in fact $y\in A$.

But, as mentioned, I do not see that in general.
Maybe you do?